# knockout multiple arrays bind to table with rowspan

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Please refer this html, I use knockoutjs to generate the report.

 Please see **(1) and **(2) locations

If i delete  **(1) & keep **(2) location tr this works fine, but my report formatting not  get as i expect.

If i delete  **(2) & keep **(1)  i am getting error saying "Cannot find closing comment tag to match:  ko foreach: ProvinceArrayDTO "
 but what i need is to have second option and populate arrays.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

In JSFiddle [Good Format STATIC DATA](http://jsfiddle.net/Jayaruvan/yf12yp6j/)

[Bad Format Dynamic from JSON](http://jsfiddle.net/Jayaruvan/akhu8ehn/)

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>CEB Province</th>
      <th>CEB Area Office</th>
      <th>Primary Substation</th>
      <th>Meter</th>
      <th>Time Of Use</th>
      <th>Energy Initial Reading</th>
      <th>Energy Final Reading</th>
      <th>Total Energy in Time interval</th>
      <th>Total Energy</th>
      <th>Coincident Peak</th>
      <th>Remarks</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- ko foreach: ProvinceArrayDTO -->
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: ProvinceName, attr: {rowspan: RowCount }"></td>
      <!-- ko foreach: AreaArrayDTO -->
      <td data-bind="text: AreaName, attr: {rowspan: RowCount }"></td>
      <!-- ko foreach: SubStationArrayDTO -->
      <td data-bind="text: SubStaionName, attr: {rowspan: RowCount }"></td>
      <!-- ko foreach: MetersArrayDTO -->
      <td data-bind="text: MeterName, attr: {rowspan: RowCount }"></td>
      <!-- ko foreach: MetersReadingArrayDTO -->
      <td class="auto-style5">Day</td>
      <td class="auto-style7">LastMnValue</td>
      <td class="auto-style2" data-bind="text: DayValue"></td>
      <td class="auto-style2">difference</td>


      <td class="auto-style4" rowspan="3">total</td>
      <td rowspan="3" data-bind="text: CoincidentPeak"></td>
      <td rowspan="3" data-bind="text: Remarks"></td>

    </tr>**(1)

    <td class="auto-style5">Peek</td>
    <td class="auto-style7">9804328</td>
    <td class="auto-style2">9523478</td>
    <td class="auto-style2">280,850</td>





    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
    </tr>**(2)
    <!-- /ko -->


  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You cannot use `<!-- /ko --></tr><!-- /ko -->` to close tags. Knockout doesn't build the dom by concatenating strings, it parses them out into template-objects. It isn't able to understand an unclosed tag and create a template when you do this.

Comment: Thank you  Tyrsius. But in my case as you can  see there are nested arrays, within arrays..  even in the template  situation is same. Any way i got my result using html binding in knockout,as described below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the views!

I've generated total table layout via javascript and used knockout's  html binding.

In Knockout

```js
self.DetailedReport = ko.observable();

function GenerateHtmlTableFronJson(){
  //JSON parse here ang generate HTML  
  return ("<table> ..... </table>");
  }

self.DetailedReport (GenerateHtmlTableFronJson());
```

In HTML

```html
<div data-bind="html: DetailedReport"></div>
```